# Unexpected behavior when trying to increment a c pointer by n bytes in custom malloc function

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to implement my own malloc function in C but I get some unexpected behaviors. My design in pseudo-code is as follows:

To initialize the heap I do the following:

- Get size of a memory page using "sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)" and store in global variable g_pagesize. I assume this is in bytes.
- Get process memory start and push back breakpoint using "sbrk(g_pagesize)", return is previous break point which I assume is the start of the processes memory space which I save in a variable called g_start.
- Get end of process memory space using "sbrk(0)" and save it in a variable called g_end.

For allocated memory blocks I use structs to define headers that works as a linked list.

```
typedef struct header
{
    size_t m_size;
    struct header *m_next;
} header_st;
```

I define one such header at "g_start" called "g_free", I set the m_size of it to g_pagesize - sizeof(header_st) to account for its own size. I set the m_next to (void *) NULL. I define a second header as g_used, which will be the entry point for finding used memory blocks, this is initialized as (void *) NULL.

To allocate memory I define a function which takes how many bytes I want to allocate as an size_t argument called bytes_size. Then the function works as follows:

- Save address of current g_free in a variable called blk.
- Increment address of g_free to follow directly after new allocated block, I do this by setting g_free += (sizeof(header_st) + bytes_size.
- Set blk->m_size = bytes_size and blk->m_next = g_used.
- Update g_used to be the last allocated block by setting g_used = blk.

What I expected here is a sequential allocation of blocks where g_free is always at the smallest unallocated memory address and each "used block" follows each other with no allocated memory in between them. Instead I seem to get much larger increments than I assumed, or I'm doing something wrong when try to print the heap info to the terminal. My code looks like this:

```
#include "../include/iron_rabbit_gc.h"
#include "stddef.h" // used for type size_t, ptrdiff_t (unsigned long %lu)
#include "stdbool.h"    // used for type bool (int)
#include "unistd.h" // contains sbrk method
#include "stdio.h"  // used for printf method
#include "string.h" // used for memcpy method
#include "stdint.h"

// global variables
bool g_active = false;
size_t g_pagesize;
intptr_t g_start;
intptr_t g_end;
size_t g_capacity;
header_st *g_used;
header_st *g_free;

void IR_init()
{
    // init heap
    g_pagesize = g_capacity = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    g_start = (intptr_t) sbrk(g_pagesize);
    g_end = (intptr_t) sbrk(0);

    // init ptr to free memory blocks
    g_free = (header_st *) g_start;
    g_free->m_size = g_capacity - sizeof(header_st);
    g_free->m_next = (header_st *) NULL;

    // init ptr to used memory
    g_used = (header_st *) NULL;

    // set heap as active
    g_active = true;
}

void IR_info()
{
    // make sure heap is initiated
    if (g_active == false)
    {
        printf("### HEAP INFO ###\n");
        printf("\tHeap is not initiated..\n");
        printf("### END ###\n");
        return;
    }

    // general heap info
    printf("### HEAP INFO ###\n");
    printf("\t%p [0]\tHeap start\n",
        (void *) g_start );
    printf("\t%p [%li]\tHeap end\n",
        (void *) g_end,
        g_end - g_start);
    
    // used memory info
    size_t i = 0;
    for (header_st *ptr = g_used; ptr != (header_st *) NULL; ptr = ptr->m_next, i++)
    {
        printf("\t%p [%li]\tUsed block %li (Size: %lu)\n",
            (void *) ptr,
            (intptr_t) ptr - g_start,
            i, ptr->m_size
        );
    } // end of used memory loop
    
    // free memory info
    i = 0;
    for (header_st *ptr = g_free; ptr != (void *) NULL; ptr = ptr->m_next, i++)
    {
        printf("\t%p [%li]\tFree block %li (Size: %lu)\n",
            (void *) ptr,
            (ptrdiff_t) ((char *) ptr - (char *) g_start),
            i, ptr->m_size
        );
    } // end of free memory loop
    
    printf("### END ###\n");
}

void *IR_malloc(size_t bytes_size)
{
    if (g_active == false)
        IR_init();

    // calculate new block size
    size_t block_size = sizeof(header_st) + bytes_size;
    printf("Block size: %lu\n", block_size);

    // update free ptr
    header_st *blk = g_free;
    g_free += block_size;

    // update new block
    blk->m_size = bytes_size;
    blk->m_next = g_used;
    
    // update used ptr
    g_used = blk;

    return g_used + sizeof(header_st);
}
```

And the results I get when trying to allocate some things is:

```
Block size: 20
### HEAP INFO ###
    0x55ff14354000 [0]  Heap start
    0x55ff14355000 [4096]   Heap end
    0x55ff14354000 [0]  Used block 0 (Size: 4)
    0x55ff14354140 [320]    Free block 0 (Size: 0)
### END ###
Block size: 29
### HEAP INFO ###
    0x55ff14354000 [0]  Heap start
    0x55ff14355000 [4096]   Heap end
    0x55ff14354140 [320]    Used block 0 (Size: 13)
    0x55ff14354000 [0]  Used block 1 (Size: 4)
    0x55ff14354310 [784]    Free block 0 (Size: 0)
### END ###
Block size: 24
### HEAP INFO ###
    0x55ff14354000 [0]  Heap start
    0x55ff14355000 [4096]   Heap end
    0x55ff14354310 [784]    Used block 0 (Size: 8)
    0x55ff14354140 [320]    Used block 1 (Size: 13)
    0x55ff14354000 [0]  Used block 2 (Size: 4)
    0x55ff14354490 [1168]   Free block 0 (Size: 0)
### END ###
Returned values
ptr1: 0x55ff14354100 (5)
ptr2: 0x55ff14354240 (Hello world!)
ptr3: 0x55ff14354410 (256)
```

In the first ### HEAP INFO ### block I try to allocate an int (size 4 bytes), so with the size of the header (16 bytes) I get a block size of 20. I expect the free block to be at position [20] not [320] (The number in the brackets are simply blk - g_start). Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: `size_t block_size = sizeof(header_st) + bytes_size;` and `g_free += block_size;` are flawed. You need to take *alignment* into account.

Comment: As for your problem, `IR_init` initializes the first "node" in the free heap. But `IR_malloc` doesn't initialize any "nodes" in the new heap. After the first call (and any following call) any attempt to use `g_free` as a `header_st` structure will not work.

Comment: Isolate the problem to a short sequence of code. Then you can ask about that with a [mre]. Do not expect Stack Overflow to be a service for debugging your entire routine.